# Transforming a LinkedHashSet into a List

Tags: java, algorithm, list

- Let's say the List b is a LinkedList.
- Let's say the List a is also a LinkedList.

Question:

- How do I append these list in constant time?

It is possible, because LinkedList is presumably a doubly linked list (otherwise it couldn't implement the Deque interface). And appending doubly linked list is a 0(1) operation.

The `addAll` method doesn't run in constant time.

Question:

- How do I transform a LinkedHashSet into a list in constant time?

It is also presumably possible because `LinkedHashSet` "maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumptions are based on no encapsulation - i.e. that the `LinkedHashSet` is willing to expose its internal `LinkedList` to the outside world, when I suspect it isn't.

Likewise joining two linked lists - I don't know offhand whether each node knows which list it's in, but that's certainly a possibility which would scupper your constant-time appending. Even if they don't, as soon as you attach the head of one list to the tail of the other, you end up with problems - you've got two lists both referring to the same data, which would have some odd consequences.

In other words, both of these operations are feasible in a computer science sense, and you could build your *own* implementations to support them, but that doesn't mean the Java API exposes its internals in a way which enables those operations.

Comment: Doesn't Java already have method which append LinkedList ? These method should of course use LinkedList instead of List, because they couldn't work at all with ArrayList. The same for transforming a LinkedHashSet into a LinkedList. That's the point of my questions, actually.

Comment: @Klems: No, I don't believe it does - because then you've got two LinkedList objects which share nodes. Likewise, how would you suggest creating a LinkedList from a LinkedHashSet without introducing possible corruption if the caller then modified the returned list? (It could potentially return an immutable view, I suppose.)

Comment: Oh, I see the probleme now. Well, as you said, it could return a read only list. Which is a bit like returning an iterator. However, to append 2 list, the method could clear the 2 initial lists and return the resulting list. But I see your point.

Comment: @Klems: Well, you can already return an iterator... the set itself is iterable. If you can only read from it, what would be the benefit in having a LinkedList?

Comment: We could benefit from every method which apply on List and doesn't modify them. I consider LinkedHashSet more like List than Set, actually. I don't see the point in using them like Set anyway. I have to use the list between thread.

Comment: @Klems: If you only need a list, then use a list. The point of having it as a set is that it's guaranteed that the elements are unique. Why bother with it if that's not what you want? Bear in mind that using it naively like a `List<T>` could be awful due to the O(n) access by element index.

Comment: A LinkedHashSet is like a List where you can remove an element instantly, to the expense of having to rehash the set when the load factor is reached. This is why I want to use a LinkedHashSet. I think the LinkedHashSet class should also implement the List interface.

Comment: @Klems: I think we'll have to agree to differ... but you could reasonably easily build your own implementation with that property.

Answer (score 6):

You would need to implement your own classes. The `LinkedList` class does not expose its internal node structure, so you can't just point its last node to the first node of another `LinkedList`.

The answer is similar for the `LinkedHashSet`: While it does maintain this doubly-linked list, you don't get to access it.

Comment: Since LinkedHashSet implements the abstract collection interface, you may get access to the list.. see answer by @Michael McGrady

Answer (score 1):

You do not get access to it but I suspect that Collections does, so you should not give up hope that this is a viable and quick solution to your problem.

I looked further and you are right. If you have `Set<Whatever> whatever = SOME CONSTRUCTOR` then you can code `List<Whatever> list = new LinkedList(whatever);` because a LinkedList has a Collections constructor and Set has a Collections interface.